# Como fazer o bot do discord enviar uma mensagem no privado

Tags: java

Eu coloquei o código assim

```
if (message.content.startsWith('.send')) {
message.guild.member(462005459184910339).createDM()
}
```

más ele não funciona, estou usando o discord.js

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar `message.author.send` para enviar uma mensagem no DM (lembrando que isso vai pegar o id da pessoa que digitou a mensagem)

Comment: Más como eu faço para por exemplo enviar uma mensagem direta para um certo usuário?

Answer (score 0):

utilize `message.author.send` para mandar pro usuário que executou a mensagem.
Para mandar para um usuário `client.users.cache.get("ID_Do_Usuário").send("MENSAGEM")`